# Parsing nested JSON nodes to POJOs using Google Http Java Client

Tags: java, json, jackson, google-http-client

For example I have a response with the following JSON:

```
{
    response: {
        id: 20,
        name: Stas
    }
}
```

And I want to parse it to the following object:

```
class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

How to skip the ***response*** node?

I use Google Http Java Client and it will be good if someone will answer how to do it there.
How will this lines have changed?

```
request.setParser(new JacksonFactory().createJsonObjectParser());
return request.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can now implement this in one step:

```
new JsonObjectParser.Builder(jsonFactory)
    .setWrapperKeys(Arrays.asList("response"))
    .build()
```

http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.15.0-rc/index.html

Comment: could explain this piece please? what means "one step"

Comment: Best answer so far, but the link to the javadoc is dead. [Here](https://google.github.io/google-http-java-client/releases/1.21.0/javadoc/index.html) is the link to the most recent one

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the Google Http Java Client, but if you can access the Jackson [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) you could do the following:

1.) [Enable](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#enable%28com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature%29) root unwrapping:

```
objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

2.) Add [annotation](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html) to User.class:

```
@JsonRootName("response")
class User {
    …
}
```

I hope you can use this approach.

Edit: I dug through the [google-http-java-client API](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.13.1-beta/index.html) and have come to the conclusion that you cannot access the ObjectMapper directly. In order to use the full power of Jackson you would have to write your own implementation of [JsonObjectParser](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.13.1-beta/com/google/api/client/json/JsonObjectParser.html) to wrap a 'real' Jackson parser. Sorry about that, maybe someone else could come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a native way (for this library) to solve my task. As a result I solved this problem by extending the functionality of [JsonObjectParser](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.13.1-beta/com/google/api/client/json/JsonObjectParser.html). It entails expanding of the [JacksonFactory](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/google-http-client-jackson2/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/json/jackson2/JacksonFactory.java), but it's a final class, so I used aggregation.

I wrote the following classes:

- JacksonFilteringFactory

  ```
  import com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser;
  import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

  public class JacksonFilteringFactory {
      private final JacksonFactory factory = new JacksonFactory();

      public JsonObjectParser createJsonObjectParser(String filteringNode) {
          return new FilteringJsonObjectParser(factory, filteringNode);
      }
  }
  ```
- FilteringJsonObjectParser

  ```
  import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.lang.reflect.Type;
  import java.nio.charset.Charset;

  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
  import org.json.JSONTokener;

  import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
  import com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser;
  import com.vkredmessenger.AppController;
  import com.vkredmessenger.util.StringUtils;

  public class FilteringJsonObjectParser extends JsonObjectParser {

      private String mFilteringNode;

      public FilteringJsonObjectParser(JsonFactory jsonFactory, 
              String filteringNode) {

          super(jsonFactory);

          mFilteringNode = filteringNode;
      }

      @Override
      public Object parseAndClose(InputStream in, 
              Charset charset, Type dataType)
                  throws IOException {

          String originalResponse = 
                  StringUtils.convertStreamToString(in, charset);

          String response = null;

          try {
              JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(originalResponse);
              JSONObject originalResponseObject = 
                      (JSONObject) tokener.nextValue();

              JSONObject responseObject = 
                      originalResponseObject.getJSONObject(mFilteringNode);
              response = responseObject.toString();

          } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          InputStream filteredIn = 
                  new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(charset));

          return super.parseAndClose(filteredIn, charset, dataType);
      }
  }
  ```

So, for example from my question, the result parsing code will be the following:

```
request.setParser(new JacksonFilteringFactory().createJsonObjectParser("response"));
return request.execute().parseAs(getResultType());
```